# How to hide and show SummerNote toolbar in response to focus and blur events

Tags: django, wysiwyg, summernote

How do you hide or show the SummerNote toolbar in response to focus or blur events? I have a few forms with 3 or more textareas and I'd like to see the toolbar only on the focused area. I'm using Bootstrap and SummerNote on Django forms.

I've tried with:

```
// Select all textarea tags in the form
var elements = $( "textarea" );

// Loop through all textarea elements
for (var i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var element = elements[i];
  $( '#' + element.id ).summernote({
    airMode: false,   // <-- False: Show toolbar; True: Hide toolbar
    toolbar: [
      ['style', ['style']],
      ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'subscript', 'superscript', 'clear']],
      ['color', ['color']],
      ['para', ['ol', 'ul', 'paragraph']],
      ['table', ['table']],
      ['insert', ['hr']],
      ['view', ['fullscreen']]
    ], 
    callbacks: {
      onFocus: function() {
        $( '#' + this.id ).summernote({
          airMode: false
        });
      },
      onBlur: function() {
        $( '#' + this.id ).summernote({
          airMode: true
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

without results

Comment: I'm searching for the same type of functionality.  Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to hide the toolbar you can change the style and add a display: none to the toolbar div, when focus you remove the style and when you blur you add it back.

What I'm doing is basically getting the callback event onBlur (it's called when you click outside the summernote component. I'm getting the ParentNode and comparing if user is clicking on the toolbar, if is not any of them I find the children with class .note-toolbar and I change to display: none, this will hide only the toolbar.

On the onFocus even I do the opposite, I get the note-editor and I change the display to block

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
  toolbar: [
      ['style', ['style']],
      ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'subscript', 'superscript', 'clear']],
      ['color', ['color']],
      ['para', ['ol', 'ul', 'paragraph']],
      ['table', ['table']],
      ['insert', ['hr']],
      ['view', ['fullscreen']]
    ],
      callbacks: {
          onBlur: function (e) {
              var p = e.target.parentNode.parentNode
              if (!(e.relatedTarget && $.contains(p, e.relatedTarget))) {
                  $(this).parent().children('.note-editor').children('.note-toolbar').css("display", "none");
              }
          },
          onFocus: function (e) {
              $(this).parent().children('.note-editor').children('.note-toolbar').css("display", "block");
        }
      }
});
```

if you need a smooth transition you can play around and change the height instead of the way it displays

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/guilherme-flores/pen/dyvQrKW

Comment: I don't know how to use this code in my case. Would you explain a little more... Thanks

Comment: @M.Colosso I added further explanation, basically when you initiate the summernote you register to a callback onBlur function, and after that you get the summernote again and attach to the focus event.
You can add this code to your  $(document).ready function

Comment: you won't need the airMode for that, I found out that to change the airmode you need do destroy the summernote and build it again, so I think is easier just to change the style.

Comment: can you mark as correct answer @M.Colosso ?